# my drawing in pygame is covered by something and I want to animate it what does not work

Tags: python, pygame

I made a function so I can make a 3 dimensional curve witch uses my 3d line function(I know that there may be already a version of this, but I want to learn how to do it myself) after trying to animate an controlled rotation of this curve I can only see a small part of it and it does not move at all.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, radians

def draw_3d_lines(screen, color, points_list, distance=1):
    for i in range(len(points_list) - 1):
        x1 = points_list[i][0]
        y1 = points_list[i][1]
        z1 = points_list[i][2]

        x2 = points_list[i + 1][0]
        y2 = points_list[i + 1][1]
        z2 = points_list[i + 1][2]

        # Apply translation and scaling
        x1t = int(x1 / distance + screen.get_width() / 2)
        y1t = int(y1 / distance + screen.get_height() / 2)
        x2t = int(x2 / distance + screen.get_width() / 2)
        y2t = int(y2 / distance + screen.get_height() / 2)

        a= pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x1t, y1t), (x2t, y2t),10)
        return(a)

def rotate_3d_points(points_list, angle_x, angle_y, angle_z):
    angle_x = radians(angle_x)
    angle_y = radians(angle_y)
    angle_z = radians(angle_z)

    cos_angle_x = cos(angle_x)
    sin_angle_x = sin(angle_x)
    cos_angle_y = cos(angle_y)
    sin_angle_y = sin(angle_y)
    cos_angle_z = cos(angle_z)
    sin_angle_z = sin(angle_z)

    rotated_points = []
    for point in points_list:
        x = point[0]
        y = point[1]
        z = point[2]

        # Apply rotation
        x_rotated = x * cos_angle_y - z * sin_angle_y
        y_rotated = y * cos_angle_x - z * sin_angle_x
        z_rotated = x * sin_angle_y + z * cos_angle_y

        x_final = y_rotated * sin_angle_z + x_rotated * cos_angle_z
        y_final = y_rotated * cos_angle_z - x_rotated * sin_angle_z
        z_final = z_rotated

        rotated_points.append((x_final, y_final, z_final))

    return rotated_points

def make_3d_curve(starting_point, ending_point, curve_point, step=0.01):
    t = 0
    points = []

    while t <= 1:
        # Calculate current point on the curve
        x = (1 - t) ** 2 * starting_point[0] + 2 * (1 - t) * t * curve_point[0] + t ** 2 * ending_point[0]
        y = (1 - t) ** 2 * starting_point[1] + 2 * (1 - t) * t * curve_point[1] + t ** 2 * ending_point[1]
        z = (1 - t) ** 2 * starting_point[2] + 2 * (1 - t) * t * curve_point[2] + t ** 2 * ending_point[2]
        points.append((x, y, z))
        t += step

    # Draw the curve
    return(points)

# Example usage
pygame.init()

# Set up the screen
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("3D Curve")

# Starting point
start = [-300, -200, 0]

# Ending point
end = [250, 100, 0]

# Curve control point
curve = [300, 100, 200]
curve = make_3d_curve(start, end, curve)
# Main game loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                rotate_3d_points(curve, 0,1,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rotate_3d_points(curve, 0,-1,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                rotate_3d_points(curve, 1,0,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                rotate_3d_points(curve, -1,0,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                rotate_3d_points(curve, 0,0,1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                rotate_3d_points(curve, 0,0,-1)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Clear the screen
    a = draw_3d_lines(screen, (0,255,0), curve)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I added the key event part and afterwards i moved the fill around but always got a nearly black screen what did not happen before.

Comment: I kinda used a AI two as this is the first part of repairing a 2000 line programm in better and pygame as I idiot used tkinter what just does not work for what i do

Answer (score 1):

`make_3d_curve` and `rotate_3d_points` don't update the points in the list, but return a new list of points. You need to assign the return value back to the variable. e.g.:

<s>`rotate_3d_points(curve, 0,1,0)`</s>.

```py
curve = rotate_3d_points(curve, 0, 1, 0)
```